# Setting Rails cookie to expire in 1 day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies, controllers

Looking through the docs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html, and setting a Rails cookie as follows:

`cookies[:votes_left] = { :value => 3, :expires => 24.hours.from_now }`

Inside my browser (Chrome), it's reporting the correct value but is giving me `Invalid Date` under the Expires column (Network > Cookies).

Am I setting the date incorrectly? I've tried variations on the Time object, but keep getting the same result, a **correctly valued cookie with an invalid expiration**.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that looks like a problem. What does running `24.hours.from_now` give  you in the console?  What do you get if you try `1.day.from_now`?  What version of rails are you running?

Comment: Is your server's clock incorrect?

Comment: In which browsers are you testing? I remember that I have some issues with cookies behavior between Firefox, Chrome and IE, some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this out myself and I see no issue with your code. As @Nevir said, check whether your server clock is correct. The only issue with that, if it's the wrong server time and it's actually setting the expiration before today's date, it won't set the cookie.

Try adding `Rails.logger 24.hours.from_now` just to see what it outputs.

But yes, you are setting the expires parameter properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `24.hours.from_now` generates a proper `Date` object in my rails console. With regards to your comment that it won't set the cookie; it looks like it *does* set the cookie, the value, in my case 3 is properly set, it just doesn't expire correctly.

Comment: The only thing I can then suggest beyond that is make sure all of your libraries are up-to-date.  There doesn't appear to be anything you are doing wrong.

Comment: much appreciated. yeah, it's strange. i ended up moving the logic to the server so i'm not working on this issue anymore really, but interested in figuring out the issue. i'll be sure to update.